# A non zero polynomial such that $P(T)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that if $T:V\to V$ is a linear operator (with V not necessarily finite) but with finite rank (i.e. Dim$T(V)=k$), then there's a non zero polynomial such that 
$$P(T)v=0, \forall v \in V$$

My first idea was to work with the characteristic polynomial of $T|_{T(V)}:T(V)\to T(V)$. Since $T$ is $T(V)$_invariant, the operator $T|_{T(V)}$ is well defined, and since Dim$T(V)=k$, we can calculate its characteristic polynomial. So, if we define $P$ to be the characteristic polynomial of $T|_{T(V)}$, by cayley-hamilton theorem, we know that:
$$P(T)v=0, \forall v \in T(V)$$ 
How can I extend for all $v\in V$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Can you multiply $P$ by something to get a new polynomial $Q$ such that when you evaluate $Q(T)v$, you will always be evaluating $P(T)$ on an element of $T(V)$?

A full answer is hidden below.

> Let $Q(x)=P(x)x$.  Then for any $v\in V$, $Q(T)v=P(T)Tv=0$ since $Tv\in T(V)$.

Comment: Thanks @Eric!! that was a really beautiful and elegant answer!!